# "Property Order->id_customer is empty" Prestashop 1.6 error

Tags: php, python, selenium-chromedriver, prestashop-1.6

I'm having this error *"Property Order->id_customer is empty"* occur **only** when orders are inputted and submitted via the Selenium chromedriver. I'm running PrestaShop 1.6 and I do not get this error when I enter the same order details manually.

I don't think it's an issue with the actual selenium script, but possibly with the webdriver; I thought it could due to missing data in a cookie or not actually selecting fields but when I inspected the packet from the form submission nothing was missing when compared to the manual entry.

I've also emptied the prestashop cache and deleted all the browser data from chrome in case it was due to cached data but no such luck.

I did override multiple files related to the order submission to accommodate some project requirements, specifically PaymentModule, Order, & AdminOrdersController but I don't know how that could be the issue if the manual entry works fine. I've been debugging anyway since I've been grasping for ideas and so in case it's actually due to my override I've been trying to debug variables in them but keep running into issues; I can't actually output the variables, I tried looking at PrestaShop Logs (Dev_mode is on), echoing, var_dumping, using PrestaShop's p(), and saving to file but no data comes out.

I could really use a direct solution but I at least need some new ideas for debugging.

EDIT: Here are the overridden files.

PaymentModules.php:

```
        $order_list = array();
        $order_detail_list = array();
        do {
            //changed from generateReference() 
            $reference = Order::generateReferenceOrderID($extra_vars[0]);

        } while (Order::getByReference($reference)->count());

        $this->currentOrderReference = $reference;
```

Order.php:

```
Class Order extends OrderCore
{
 //needed to abide by project requirements prefix system.
    public static function generateReference(){
        $id_shop = Context::getContext()->shop->id;

        $ref_store = "ABCD";
        if($id_shop == 1){
            $ref_store = "TCPR";
        }
        else if ($id_shop == 2){
            $ref_store = "LOER";
        }
        else if ($id_shop == 3){
            $ref_store = "TCPW";
        }

        $AUTO_INCREMENT = Db::getInstance()->getValue("
        SELECT `AUTO_INCREMENT`
        FROM  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
        WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'ts'
        AND   TABLE_NAME   = 'orders'");

        $last_id = Db::getInstance()->getValue("
        SELECT MAX(id_order)
        FROM '._DB_PREFIX_.'orders");


        if($last_id < $AUTO_INCREMENT){
            $last_id = $AUTO_INCREMENT - 1;
        }

        $result = $ref_store . str_pad((int)$last_id + 1, 5, '00000', STR_PAD_LEFT);

        return $result;

    }

    public static function generateReferenceOrderID($order_id){

        $ref_store = "SQSP";

        $result = $ref_store . str_pad((int)$order_id, 5, '00000', STR_PAD_LEFT);

        return $result;

    }

}
```

AdminOrdersController.php:

```
$employee = new Employee((int)Context::getContext()->cookie->id_employee);
//passing order message into extra_vars for use in PaymentModule
$payment_module->validateOrder(
        (int)$cart->id, (int)$id_order_state,
        $cart->getOrderTotal(true, Cart::BOTH), 
        $payment_module->displayName, 
        $this->l('Manual order -- Employee:').' '.
     substr($employee->firstname, 0, 1).'. '.$employee->lastname, 
        array(Tools::getValue('order_message')), null, false,
        $cart->secure_key);
```

Comment: Post the relevant code of your overrides, on order submission. Also, to debug in these situations i use something like file_put_contents('filelog.log', print_r($var_to_debug, true). PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);

Comment: Overrides are posted. I'll try your method for debugging.